# Cloud Dataproc to read BigQuery Views using BigQuery Connector

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to have Cloud Dataproc read BigQuery Views using the BigQuery Connector?

Also, for usecases say where there are some workloads being run in Apache Spark(Dataproc) and some workloads being run in BigQuery on the same data =>
Is it better to keep the data in Google Cloud Storage(GCS) as avro encoded format 
(or)
is it better to have the data just in BigQuery, and if it is possible to just expose an authorized view in BigQuery to be accessed by Cloud Dataproc using BigQuery Connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because BigQuery Connector exports BigQuery Tables to GCS, but BigQuery API does not support export of [BigQuery Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations) at the moment:

> You cannot run a BigQuery job that exports data from a view.